# Using Spring JpaRepository, with Hibernate 4 as the provider, on a table with composite primary key throws an IdentifierGenerationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

So as the title says. I have an entity with a composite key. The entity is:

ContractServiceLocation.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONTRACT_SERVICE_LOCATION")
@NamedQuery(name="ContractServiceLocation.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM ContractServiceLocation c")
@TypeDef(defaultForType= LocalDate.class, typeClass = LocalDateType.class)
public class ContractServiceLocation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ContractServiceLocationPK id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private LocalDate datefrom;

    private LocalDate dateto;

    @Column(length=90)
    private String details;

    @Column(nullable=false, precision=65535, scale=32767)
    private BigDecimal price;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Contract
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CONTRACT_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Contract contract;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to Location
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Location location;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to Service
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SERVICE_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Service service;

    //getters & setters
    }
```

ContractServiceLocationPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class ContractServiceLocationPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="CONTRACT_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long contractId;

    @Column(name="LOCATION_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long locationId;

    @Column(name="SERVICE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long serviceId;

    //getters & setters & equals & hashcode
    }
```

Since I'm using JpaRepository for all other entities I thought that it'd support entities with composite keys. So I defined my Dao as such:

ContractServiceLocationDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface ContractServiceLocationDao extends
        JpaRepository<ContractServiceLocation, ContractServiceLocationPK> {

}
```

However, upon calling the save method on a ContractServiceLocation entity I get a:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: null id generated for:class hr.kingict.telco.model.ContractServiceLocation; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class hr.kingict.telco.model.ContractServiceLocation
```

I've checked in debug that all composite key properties(contract, service and location) are not null. However the exception says "null id **generated** for class..." so I'm assuming it somehow tries to generate an id(even though I haven't set the @GeneratedValue annotation).

What can I do to solve this issue? Do I have to write a dao manually instead of relying on JpaRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that when I added a contract, service or location to the entity I did not update the id object to reflect that. Once I figured that out the resolution was simple. In the entity with the composite key (in my case ContractServiceLocation.java), to the setters of properties which make up the composite key I've added this piece of code:

```
public void setContract(Contract contract) {
    this.contract = contract;
    this.id.setContractId(contract.getId()); //added line
}
```

So each time I set/change a composite property, the id will reflect that.

Also this isn't perfect(but works for now) and could be improved by checking if property id is null/default and in case it is throw an exception.