# How to declare JPARepository on the basis of a composite ID?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a class with 2 ids like this

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PersonID.class)
public class Person{
   @Id
   private int id;
   @Id
   private int flag;

   ...
}
public class PersonID{
   int id;
   int flag;
}
```

I want to use `JPARepository<Person,???>` to use his methods but i don't now how !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Spring JpaRepository, with Hibernate 4 as the provider, on a table with composite primary key throws an IdentifierGenerationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156886/using-spring-jparepository-with-hibernate-4-as-the-provider-on-a-table-with-co)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
JpaRepository<Person, PersonID>
```

Comment: Remember to implement seralizable if necessary